# How to change the theme of jQuery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have been testing and playing around with jquery date picker below.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

on this page, you can click on different links and it will change the whole formatting of the datepicker (colors, etc)  when i download and test it, its coming up with a theme that i dont like.

How can I change the theme of my own website for this datepicker?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In addition to [Chris's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309604/282110), a more [direct link is here.](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)  Using themeroller, you can choose to use either a pre-built theme or .. well.. roll your own.

---

Instructions on how to use the themeroller is located [here](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/themeroller/)

Comment: Wow, themeroller huh? that's awesome. jQuery is on track to become the next holy grail of UI development.

Comment: It's unclear how to implement this theme under the website. So Ok. I just downloaded some theme and what's now?

Comment: @DmitryBoyko [this is how to use it](http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started#After_downloading:_Intro_to_using_jQuery_UI)

Comment: @Benjamin Link is dead. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564317/jquery-ui-themeroller-installing-themes#2564474) works.

Comment: Please update on Instructions on how to use the themeroller URL, it is no longer valid.

Answer (score 3):

You can go to http://jqueryui.com/ and pick a new one.

Comment: This answer doesn't really say how to actually do it.

Answer (score 3):

See this page http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started, section titled "*After downloading: Intro to using jQuery UI.*"