# Page not loading custom jQuery UI Theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, themeroller

First off, I'm aware of the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller - Installing themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564317/jquery-ui-themeroller-installing-themes) question. However, after consulting it, I continue to have problems.

When I open the `index.html` included in the installation, I get this (the correct theme):
[image: Working custom jQuery UI Theme]

However, when I work it into my page, I get the following (default/failed installation):
[image: Broken jQuery UI Theme]

First off, I don't like the Smoothness theme, and second, the font sizes are several times larger than the font on my page. I've taken both copies of `jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css` (from the `css/custom-theme` and `development-bundle/theme/custom-theme`) and copied the `custom-theme` directory to my `styles` directory, but it still doesn't work.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<link href="../styles/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js"></script>
```

And here's my directory tree:

```
pages/
    page1.html
    page2.html
styles/
    custom-theme/
        images/
            // bunch of files for jQuery UI theme
        jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.css
    global.css
    reset.css  // note that on the page, this is defined before any other CSS
scripts/
    jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.js
    // bunch of other custom scripts
```

Given this, why won't it display correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug to see whether your CSS files are being loaded. If they are being included successfully, use Firebug again to select a DOM element inside the popup and see where the CSS styles are coming from (i.e. which file).

Comment: A) I'm using Chrome, and B) it's loading, according to Chrome/WebKit's Dev Tools. There are no other CSS styles overriding the jQuery UI theme.

Comment: Hover over the popup, right click and Inspect Element. Try adding a few `!important` values to CSS properties and see if anything changes. Maybe the native styles in the JS are overriding your own CSS styles? Have you tried placing your CSS `<link>` below the JS `<script>` inclusion?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, importing the jQuery UI library doesn't have native styling (and besides, that didn't change anything). And adding the `!important` vales to the relevant properties didn't change anything either.

Comment: I can't really do more than speculate at the moment without seeing it. Can you try a jsFiddle? Also, seems stupid to ask, but have you cleaned your cache?

Comment: For some reason - God knows why - clearing the cache made it work. Thanks for your help.