# Adding themes to the themeroller

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, themes, themeroller

BEFORE YOU SAY IT:  I have read [jQuery UI ThemeRoller - Installing themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564317/jquery-ui-themeroller-installing-themes) and it was no help.

I have been searching and searching, and the documentation on the jQuery site is 3 sentences of un-helpfullness.  I added the jQuery UI themeroller on my website, (previously having the 'smoothness' theme) but now, since they are the only ones the themeroller comes with, it is between the UI lightness and UI darkness.  I am trying to add the 'smoothness' theme back on to my website, as a themeroller option, but I don't have the 'theme' folder, or the 'all.css' file needed.  Anyone have any suggestions/ideas, or better, know any hosted versions of the file (could not find any)?

Comment: So does the question you linked describe your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Download an example here http://www.filedropper.com/themeroller

In this, I have added the themeroller controller same as [Jquery themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) and it will switch themes as per the theme selected by Dropdownlist. To change the themes I used themeswitcher plugin which you can find [here.](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/)

[Here](http://www.filedropper.com/jquerythemes) is another example with using Dropdownlist to select theme. In this you have to change the css file manually to set the theme, i.e.
in index.html change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/ui-darkness/jquery.ui.all.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.all.css">
```